# Java Thread Creation

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create a thread using runnable method .The code is below

```
public class NewClass implements Runnable{
     public static void main(String[] agrg){
            NewClass n =new NewClass();
            n.start();
      }
      void start(){
            Thread th=new Thread();
            th.start();
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread");
      }
}
```

In this override method run should me call ,but it is not happening

Comment: You need to pass the Runnable instance to your thread

Comment: Answer updated with correction.

Answer (score 3):

Your `run()` method is belong to `NewClass` which is not a Thread, it's a worker.

So, no body going to call `run()` method of `NewClass`

In java, when you are creating a worker by implementing `Runnable`, you should override the `run()` method only. And pass an instance of this worker to a Thread, like

```
new Thread(new NewClass()).start();
```

So you can do the following

```
public class NewClass implements Runnable{
     public static void main(String[] agrg){
            NewClass n =new NewClass();
            n.start();
      }
      void start(){
            Thread th=new Thread(this);
            th.start();
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `Runnable` instance to the [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) class constructor.

In your case, replace `Thread th=new Thread();` with `Thread th=new Thread(new NewClass())`.

When you create a Thread class instance using `Thread th=new Thread();` the default implementation of the [Thread.run()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) method is invoked (which does nothing).

Thus, you need override the `run()` method in your implementing class (NewClass in your case) which you have done correctly. But you also need to specify the implementing class instance to the Thread class constructor using `Thread th=new Thread(new NewClass())`

Comment: I think in this case, start() should better receive NewClass Object as paramater to create a thread of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting a new Thread, but that thread isn't actually doing anything. The new thread has no connection whatsoever to the class it is started from or the code that class contains.

When you implement a Runnable, you usually perform it by creating a thread with that runnable as an argument.

```
Runnable myRunnable = new NewClass();
Thread myThread = new Thread( myRunnable );`
myThread.start(); // will execute myRunnable.run() in background
```

or by using an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html).

```
Executor myExecutor = new SheduledThreadPoolExecutor(NUM_OF_PARALLEL_THREADS);
Runnable myRunnable = new NewClass();
myExecutor.execute(myRunnable); // will execute myRunnable.run() in background as soon as one of the parralel threads is available
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Thread class is a separate class from your main class.

```
    public class ThreadClass implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread");
        }
    }

    public class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] agrg) {
            ThreadClass t = new ThreadClass();
            Thread th = new Thread(t);
            th.start();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, no one is there to run your "run" method. You can extend Thread and can ask the run method to do the work just by starting the Thread

```
public class NewClass extends Thread{
    public static void main(String[] agrg){
       NewClass n =new NewClass();
       n.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Thread");
    }
```

}